# Filtering out Movies in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm developing a Movie App in Flutter. TMDB API link https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction. I want to know how to filter a Movies list by Genre. Here is a screenshot of my app.

[image]

The genre UI is a horizontal list and we can select any genre. Here the screenshot of it.

[image]

I want to filter my movies list UI according to genre selection, whether required genre is selected show list accordingly and if unselected show the original list. If possible, also provide some insights on multiple genre filtration.

Here is my Genre UI code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_movies_app/utility/Size_Config.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';

class Genres extends StatefulWidget {
  const Genres({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GenresState createState() => _GenresState();
}

class _GenresState extends State<Genres> {
  var genres = [
    [28, "Action"],
    [12, "Adventure"],
    [16, "Animation"],
    [35, "Comedy"],
    [80, "Crime"],
    [99, "Documentary"],
    [18, "Drama"],
    [10751, "Family"],
    [14, "Fantasy"],
    [36, "History"],
    [27, "Horror"],
    [10402, "Music"],
    [9648, "Mystery"],
    [10749, "Romance"],
    [878, "Science Fiction"],
    [10770, "TV Movie"],
    [53, "Thriller"],
    [10752, "War"],
    [37, "Western"]
  ];
  List<bool> temp = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) temp.add(false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPadding / 2),
      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
      //color: Colors.red,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: genres.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (temp[index]) {
                    setState(() {
                      temp[index] = false;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      temp[index] = true;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: kDefaultPadding / 2),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: kDefaultPadding,
                      vertical: kDefaultPadding / 4),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: temp[index] ? Colors.amber : Colors.transparent,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: temp[index]
                              ? Colors.transparent
                              : Colors.black26),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                  child: Text(
                    genres[index].last.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: temp[index]
                            ? Colors.white
                            : kTextColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                        fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using provider package for my state management and API (TMDB movies API) integration. Here is some code from my provider dart file.

```
List<nowPlaying.Result> _nowPlayingMovies = [];
List<nowPlaying.Result> get getNowPlaying => [..._nowPlayingMovies];

Future<void> getNowPlayingMovies({required String type}) async {
    try {
      nowPlaying.NowPlayingModel? nowPlayingModel =
          await GetMoviesTvShows.nowPlayingMovies(type: type, page: 1);
      if (nowPlayingModel != null) {
        List<nowPlaying.Result> temp = [];
        nowPlayingModel.results.forEach((result) {
          if (result.title.isNotEmpty && result.overview.isNotEmpty) {
            temp.add(result);
          }
        });
        _nowPlayingMovies = temp;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      print(e);
      print(s);
    }
  }
```

This is the filtering code I've come up. But I don't want to change the original list as I'll required it when the genre is not selected.

```
Future<void> filterByGenre({required int genreId}) async {
    try {
      List<nowPlaying.Result> nowPlayingTemp = [];
      _nowPlayingMovies.forEach((element) {
        if (element.genreIds.contains(genreId)) nowPlayingTemp.add(element);
      });
      List<moviesModel.Result> popularTemp = [];
      _popularLS.forEach((element) {
        if (element.genreIds.contains(genreId)) popularTemp.add(element);
      });
      List<moviesModel.Result> topRatedTemp = [];
      _topRatedLS.forEach((element) {
        if (element.genreIds.contains(genreId)) topRatedTemp.add(element);
      });
      List<moviesModel.Result> upcomingTemp = [];
      _upComingLS.forEach((element) {
        if (element.genreIds.contains(genreId)) upcomingTemp.add(element);
      });
      _nowPlayingMovies = nowPlayingTemp;
      _popularLS = popularTemp;
      _topRatedLS = topRatedTemp;
      _upComingLS = upcomingTemp;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e, s) {
      print(e);
      print(s);
    }
  }
```

Can you help out your fellow developer?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with activating and deactivation genres is dangerous.

Instead you can create a object for genre Like:

```
class Genre {
  int id;
  String title;
  bool active;

  Genre(this.id, this.title, {this.active = false});

  void toggleActive() {
    active = !active;
  }
}
```

With this you will have an easier interface to activate and deactivate genre.

Now, lets see how to filter movies.

Consider some way of getting all movies together.

```
class Movie {
  List<int> genreIds;
  String name;

  Movie(this.name,this.genreIds);
}

class MovieGenerator {
  static Future<List<Movie>> getMovies() async{
    return [
      Movie("Dairy kid", [1,2]),
      Movie("Dairy Man", [1]),
    ];
  }
}
```

The Filtering can be done in following ways :

```
         FutureBuilder<List<Movie>>(
          future: MovieGenerator.getMovies(),
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              var movies = snapshot.data;
              var selectedGenres = genres.where((e) => e.active).map((e) => e.id);
              var filteredMovies = movies.where((a) {
                bool shouldAdd = false;                
                for(int i = 0; i<a.genreIds.length; i++) {
                  if(selectedGenres.contains(a.genreIds[i])) {
                    shouldAdd = true;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                
                return shouldAdd;
              }).toList();
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: List.generate(
                 filteredMovies.length,
                  (i) => Text(filteredMovies[i].name) 
                ),
              );
            }else {
              return Container();
            }
          }
        ),
```

So, the whole code might look something like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Genre {
  int id;
  String title;
  bool active;

  Genre(this.id, this.title, {this.active = false});

  void toggleActive() {
    active = !active;
  }
}

class Movie {
  List<int> genreIds;
  String name;
  
  Movie(this.name,this.genreIds);
}

class MovieGenerator {
  static Future<List<Movie>> getMovies() async{
    return [
      Movie("Dairy kid", [1,2]),
      Movie("Dairy Man", [1]),
    ];
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Genre> genres;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    genres = [
      Genre(1, "Action", active: true),
      Genre(2, "Comedy"),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: List.generate(genres.length, (i) {
              var cur = genres[i];
              return Chip(
                  title: cur.title,
                  active: cur.active,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      genres[i].toggleActive();
                    });
                  });
            }),
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder<List<Movie>>(
          future: MovieGenerator.getMovies(),
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              var movies = snapshot.data;
              var selectedGenres = genres.where((e) => e.active).map((e) => e.id);
              var filteredMovies = movies.where((a) {
                bool shouldAdd = false;                
                for(int i = 0; i<a.genreIds.length; i++) {
                  if(selectedGenres.contains(a.genreIds[i])) {
                    shouldAdd = true;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                
                return shouldAdd;
              }).toList();
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: List.generate(
                 filteredMovies.length,
                  (i) => Text(filteredMovies[i].name) 
                ),
              );
            }else {
              return Container();
            }
          }
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class Chip extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool active;
  final Function onTap;

  const Chip({Key key, this.title, this.active, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(999.0),
            color: active ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
          ),
          child: Text(title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: active ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

You can run this code in dartpad.dev to check it out.